# Navigating between splits

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I wanted to settup [vim-tmux-navigation](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) like navigation on intellij IDE and only way to settup this is from IdeaVim so my configuration in settings -> keymap looks like this:

- VimWindowDown_____      alt J
- VimWindowLeft______      alt L
- VimWindowRight_____alt H
- VimWindowUp_______               alt K

But when I split the windows it's not working.... Is this a bug or I'm missing some stuff?

Oh and don't suggest me switcher for my problem...

Comment: 7 years later...ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for setting up custom keys for Vim actions is the ~/.ideavimrc file. You can use the standard Vim map/nmap/noremap/imap/... commands there. For example:

```
nmap <A-J> <C-W>j
```

For potential keymap conflicts between the Vim emulation and the IDE see Settings | Vim Emulation.

Chaning Vim actions via Settings | Keymap is not recommended.

Comment: I joust found possible error. ideavimrc to not except mixed intendations for example `. . \t . . . . nmap <A-J> <C-w>j` >> this will not work!

Comment: Oh and is it possible to use noremap ?

Comment: The parser for ~/.ideavimrc is very basic. It might be confused by so many things. Yes, it supports `noremap` as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got a partial answer.

There is a "Go To Next Splitter" and "Go To Previous Splitter" commands in IntelliJ. So in the keymap settings, change or add keystrokes for those commands to C-h and C-l (or whatever you want). If you are using ideavim, don't forget to override those keymap settings so that C-h and C-l are set to use the IDE. C-h and C-l will probably already be used so be sure you don't need the existing hotkey before you make the change.

This solution will at least allow you to move left/right quickly. Not sure it's going to be possible to move between up/down splits without doing some scripting or if that's even possible to do with scripting.